# no internet connection, but have signal in wifi

Tags: internet, connection, signal

I cannot access yahoo.com, google etc in my browser, but I have signal in my WiFi, how can I access the internet again?

Please can you tell me how to configure and solve my problem,

Thanks

Comment: Can you `ping google.com`? Can you `ping 8.8.8.8`?

Comment: Do you have the ability to plug it in with a cat5-6 cable? If so does that work?

Comment: yes in cable it works @Gui

Comment: but I don't have access in Wifi

Comment: @user it doesn't work

Comment: so, what can I do to have good WiFi connection?